# How to get distinct values as a single document in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I do a `SELECT DISTINCT c.Damage.Cause_of_Damage FROM c`, where `Cause_of_Damage` is an array, I get a lot of documents with individual values back. Is there a way to concat all of them to a single array in a single result document?

Answer (score 1):

It works using a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE i
FROM c
JOIN i IN c.Damage.Cause_of_Damage
```